# MySQL SELECT add column to a query if not selected

Tags: php, mysql

I have a query like this (in PHP):

```
SELECT ".$info." FROM products WHERE id IN (".$id.")".($type != "" ? " AND p_type = '".$type."'" : "").";"
```

`$info` can be whatever (even `*`), but I want to get also 2 additional columns in the result (`id, p_type`), even if they are not selected they must be there, I've tried this `"SELECT id, p_type, ".$info." ...` but it gives me an error, this syntax is not correct, any help?

Thanks.

Comment: What does `$info` usually look like? Can you provide an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I solved it! If `$info = "*"` it needs to be first, so it become `"SELECT ".$info.", id, p_type ...`

Answer (score 0):

it might be becouse the variable is empty try this :

```
 $info=($info=='')?'id, p_type':$info.',id, p_type';
   SELECT ".$info." FROM products WHERE id IN (".$id.")".($type != "" ? " AND p_type = '".$type."'" : "").";"
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply create an array as follows may be named

```
$getColumns = array("id", "p_type");
```

Now you have to add columns to this array one by one as follows:-

```
$getColumns[] = "column3";
$getColumns[] = "column4";
$getColumns[] = "column5";
```

And so on and if you want's to get all columns simply add "*" to array

```
$getColumns[] = "*";
```

then to get list of all columns

```
$columns = (in_array("*", $getColumns))? "*": implode(", ", $getColumns);
```

Now you can use $columns in your query. That's all....